# Cant get my service to work - loading

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

Have a simple REST service that returns a list of items of type BlogPost from a database. The api works fine, its my Angular code that Im still rusty on.  I think my problem is simple and has to do with loading a feature module into the root module.  Im getting an error loading the http module

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http!
>   Error: No provider for Http!

API method

```
   [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetBlogPosts(BlogSearchModel b)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage retval = new HttpResponseMessage();
        List<BlogPost> result = dmgr.GetBlogPosts(b);
        retval = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        return retval;

    }
```

I have a feature module that uses this api from a service.
service method:

app.module.ts

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ItModule } from './itdept/itdept.module';
import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routes';
//import { ItBlogService } from './itdept/itdept.blog.service'



@NgModule({
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpModule,
      ItModule,
      HomeModule ,
      routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],  
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class MainModule { }
```

itdept.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";   
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
//import { ModelModule } from "./model/blogpost.module";
import { BlogPostComponent } from "./blog-post-detail.component";
import { ItdeptComponent } from "./itdept.component";
import { ItBlogService } from "./itdept.blog.service";

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
    declarations: [BlogPostComponent, ItdeptComponent],
    //exports: [BlogPostComponent, ItdeptComponent],
    providers: [ItBlogService]

})
export class ItModule {

}
```

itdept.blog.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BlogPost } from '../model/blogpost';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {User} from './user';



@Injectable()
export class ItBlogService {

    _baseUrl: string = '';

    constructor(private http:Http) {
        console.log('ItDeptBlogService Service created.', http);
    }


    getBlogPosts(): Observable<BlogPost[]> {
        var headers = new Headers();        
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');        
        return this.http.post("http://dlocal.test.com/api/fNet/GetBlogPosts",
            { postDate: '', bodyContent: '', Title: '' })          
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return <BlogPost[]>res.json();
            }).catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

    // update

    // new

}
```

Then a component that uses this service:

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItBlogService } from './itdept.blog.service';
import { BlogPost } from '../model/blogpost';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
    selector: 'itdept',
    templateUrl: 'app/itdept/itdept.component.html'
})
export class ItdeptComponent {

    public name: string;
    public BlogPostList: BlogPost[];

    constructor(private blogService: ItBlogService) {      

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getBlogPosts();
    }

    getBlogPosts() {
        this.blogService.getBlogPosts()
            .subscribe(data => { this.BlogPostList  = data });        
    }
}
```

itdept.component.html

```
<div>This is the IT area</div>


<div class="row">
    <div ng2-ngFor="let b of BlogPostList" class="col-md-5">

    </div>

</div>
```

BlogPost class

```
import { IBlogPostModel } from "./interfaces";

export class BlogPost implements IBlogPostModel{

    id: number;
    title: string;
    bodyContent: string;
    tagList: string;
    dateCreated: string;
    dateUpdated: string;
    createdUser: string;
    updatedUser: string;

    constructor(values: Object = {}) 
    { 
        Object.assign(this, values);
    }
};
```

[ **update1** - error detail ]
As seen in Chrome dev console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http! Error: No provider for Http!
    at injectionError (reflective_errors.ts:73)
    at noProviderError (reflective_errors.ts:108)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:500)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:543)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:404)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:349)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (ng_module.ts:101)
    at _createClass (ng_module.ts:151)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (ng_module.ts:121)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (ng_module.ts:101)
    at injectionError (reflective_errors.ts:73)
    at noProviderError (reflective_errors.ts:108)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (reflective_injector.ts:500)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (reflective_injector.ts:543)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (reflective_injector.ts:404)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (reflective_injector.ts:349)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (ng_module.ts:101)
    at _createClass (ng_module.ts:151)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (ng_module.ts:121)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (ng_module.ts:101)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:783)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:754)
    at zone.js:831
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:288)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:191)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1370)
```

[ **update 2** ] 
Strange, I just started a new debug session with Firefox, pulled open the dev console and seen a different error that related to my error handler in ItBlogService.ts.  The error mentioned that Observable.throw was not a function, which led me to add this to the top of ItBlogService.ts

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
```

This was part of the problem, and once I added that I could see a few other issues.  I think Ive almost got it now.

Comment: can you post your module.ts

Comment: updated, see above

Comment: not sure why you are importing httpModule in your lazily loading module again. And in app.module.ts what is HomeModule that you are importing. check this post, might be helpful....https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html

Comment: Can You provide error???

Comment: Salim, see update1 above

Comment: @JayDeeEss - not using lazy loading, but yes I removed the httpModule from my feature module

Comment: ok...in your app.module why are you importing HomeModule and ItModule??

Comment: Those are 'feature' modules

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you declare it in your module.ts

```html
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ HttpModule ]
});

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

in itdept.blog.service.ts

```
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
```

add Headers

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: Yep, doing that but still same error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Http!
Error: No provider for Http!

Comment: add in your modules, after you export the class: platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(modulenamehere);

Comment: Im using systemjs, which does that in a file called main.ts - thats where I do that